# How do I make a textbox visible only after choosing a specific list item?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created a request form to request class booking for an activity. within this request I need to put a column called activity type with the different types in a radio button, then if I choose a certain type i would like for a textbox to appear so they could enter a number in it. But that only if that one choice is chosen. is that possible?

also how can I resolve the double booking problem in SharePoint calendar?

Comment: Please add more details about your problems.

Comment: I think he wants to show/hide a text field based on the value of a drop down.

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, my understanding is that you want to prevent double booking in SharePoint Calendar.

Here is a sandbox solution your reference:

[Calendar with Resources](http://spform.com/media/default/calendarwithresources/calendarwithresources.wsp)

More details in the link below:

[Reservation of resources in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2013 Online in Office 365](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/reservation-of-resources-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-2013)

Or You can use a workflow to achieve it.

[SharePoint: Double Booking with the Calendar](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Double-Booking-with-the-Calendar.aspx)